# How to refresh the Ext.List

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my application im using the Ext.List to show the contents from JSON,Initially JSON data showing properly .If when i add search keyword the response from JSON result is being added with previous content, ie,

Initially table

```
 Car
 Bus
 Jeep
```

If am search for Car , the table showing in the following

```
 Car
 Bus
 Jeep
 Car
```

But i want to display only the new result,Here the code

**SEARCH**

```
 {
xtype: 'button',
ui:'normal',
width:'20%',
    text: 'Search',
    handler: function() 
      {
    App.gvars.keywd=Ext.getCmp("searchfd").getValue();
    searchfriends();
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('searchfriendslist1').load();// i have added the method to refresh table but no use
       }
  }
```

**Search table**

```
 var searchfrieandtab=  Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                                 width: 320,
                                 height: 290,
                                 id : 'searchfriendslist1',
                                 itemTpl: ['<div style="margin:0px;background:#fff;" >'+
                                           '<table style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:40px;" width="100%" >'+
                                           '<tr><td style="padding:2px 5px;width:90%;"><span><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{userImage}"/>'+
                                           '</span><span>{userFirstName}</span></td>'+
                                           '<td style="padding:2px 10px;width:10%;">'+
                                           '<img src="resources/img/addplus.png" onclick="invitefriends(\'{userId}\')"/>'+
                                           '</td></tr></table></div>'].join(),
                                 listeners : {
                                 itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
                                 if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
                                 var data = record.getData();
                                 var userId = data.userId;
                                 var itemPurchased = data.itemPurchased;
                                              invitefriends(userId);
                                 }
                                 }
                                 }
                                 });
```

**JSON**

```
 function searchfriends() {
alert(App.gvars.keywd);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: App.gvars.apiurl + 'SearchFriends/userID='+App.gvars.userid+'/keywords='+App.gvars.keywd,
    method: "GET",
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: function (response) {
            var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    Ext.getCmp('searchfriendslist1').setData(respObj.searchFriends);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
       var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
       Ext.Msg.alert("Error",response.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

How to refresh or clear the list before the JSON call.Please help to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
searchfrieandtab.getStore().removeAll();
```